# SQL Server stored procedure in VBA Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I had a look online and found many similar posts but nothing I could use to sort my issue.

I'm trying to access a stored procedure from SQL Server in VBA (Excel 2019), but I'm always facing the same errors, one or another:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Could someone have a look and give advice?

```vb
Sub SQP_Procedure_Into_Excel()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=##########;Initial Catalog=##########;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
        Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            conn.Open strConn
        
        Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "[###].[############]"
        .CommandType = 4 ' adCmdStoredProc
    End With
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Dim startcol As Long
    startcol = 1
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Do While Not rs Is Nothing
    
            Dim col As Long
            For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, startcol + col) = rs.Fields(col).Name
            Next col
            .Cells(2, startcol).CopyFromRecordset rs
    
            startcol = startcol + rs.Fields.Count + 1
            Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
        Loop
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think nextrecordset is the correct method. You probably want rs.Next

Comment: That is not even the issue, as the code is not stopping on the "CopyFromRecordSet" part. I had tried other ways too but nothing work

Comment: Always helps to say exactly which line is giving you what error...

Comment: The line changes according to what I'm trying to do. If I change the CopyFromRecordset (that is actually giving me the error), to another version of loop, that the error goes to "object cannot be closed" pointin to an error on rs.EOF

Comment: Right after `Set rs = cmd.Execute` add `Debug.Print rs.State` to check the returned recordset is open before trying to read from it.  Value should be 1 if open.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/state-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver16   If not open then your stored procedure needs investigating.

Answer (score 0):

As `conn` and `ActiveConnection` are objects you have to use `Set` to refer to the `conn` as `ActiveConnection:

```vb
With cmd
   Set .ActiveConnection = conn
   .CommandText = "[###].[############]"
   .CommandType = 4 ' adCmdStoredProc
End With
```

Comment: Hey Ike, havent thought of that one. I still have the property method error thou, pointing to the "copyFromRecordedset rs"

Comment: ah - I didn't see that: you are using `With ActiveWorkbook` and then refer to `.cells` -> that doesn't work. You must have a **worksheet** as base of `With` not a workbook

Comment: That cant be the problem. I tried it with worksheets but still the same error, I think it's the version of excel not having "copyfromrecordedset" option. 2019 here

Comment: Regarding Ike's indication of the use of Set, It is an anomaly in ADODB that despite being an Object, the ActiveConnection property can be either Let or Set. I think in older versions of Office, Set actually caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate with `CopyFromRecordset`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Const startcol = 1

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConn As String, col As Long
    
    strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=##########;Initial Catalog=##########;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn
        
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "[###].[############]"
        .CommandType = 4 ' adCmdStoredProc
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, startcol + col) = rs.Fields(col).Name
        Next col
        .Cells(2, startcol).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "Application defined or object defined error" message, highlighting the "copyfromRecordSet" row

Comment: Does you procedure create a recordset or is an update ?

Comment: It's bringing the data from the DB to a clean spredsheet

Comment: If Microsoft SQL Server test with `.CommandText = "[sys].[sp_who]`. Do you have admin privileges ?

Comment: I do have access to the servers now, just lack knowledge on how to work on them. We already have a team who create the scripts, view/procedures, so I'm trying to work on a way to get those scripts incorporated in Excel to make things easier.